# Is it possible to integrate the following expression with respect to $l$?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I am trying to integrate the following expression with respect to $l$

$$
\frac{\sqrt{1-2 \epsilon  \log \left(\sqrt{2} l\right)}}{\sqrt{1-k\, l^2
   \left(1-2 \epsilon  \log \left(\sqrt{2} l\right)\right)}}
$$

I tried different substitutions and Mathemtica but couldn't do the integration. Does anyone know how to integrate the above expression with respect to $l$ using substitution or any other method?

Thanks.